# Unable to fetch paragraph's multi field values inside node twig

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have a content type as "worker". I have a Paragraph "test" and I am referencing "test" paragraph inside my content type "worker". This allows multiple values to be saved.

How can I get the multiple "test" paragraph's `field_name` inside my node--worker.html.twig file directly?

I am able to get the single value of that field like below:

```
{{ node.field_test.entity.field_cdsfasdf.value }}
```

But, unable to fetch the multiple values for this field inside my node--worker.html.twig. I tried using for loop to fetch the multiple values like the code below:

```
{% for key, item in node.field_para %}
    {{ key }}
    <div class="item"> {{ item.entity.field_cdsfasdf.value }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But, I am facing the following error:

```
Exception: Object of type Drupal\entity_reference_revisions\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceRevisionsItem cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line 465 of DRUPAL_ROOT\exp\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension.php).

Exception: Object of type Drupal\node\Entity\Node cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line 465 of DRUPAL_ROOT\exp\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension.php).
```

Comment: can try using theming paragraph  field [https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/paragraphs/theming-in-paragraphs-for-drupal-8]

Comment: Actualy, I want to get the entity reference values inside m node.twig file, but notin paragraphs.twig

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head...

For multiple value fields you either render out the paragraph field itself:

```
{{ content.field_paragraph_field_name }}
```

and let Drupal handle the multiple value rendering, or do your own loop:

```
{% for item in content.field_paragraph_field_name %}
  {{ item.your.array.keys.here.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Try:

```
{% for item in content.field_paragraph_field_name %}
  {{ dump(item | keys) }}
{% endfor %}
```

to see what keys you need to follow to your value.

---

I *do* recommend doing this kind of theming in a paragraph--paragraph-name.html.twig file, and then just printing the field in node.html.twig.

For a paragraph template file, it would look something like:

```
{% for item in content.field_paragraph_field_name['#items'] %}
  <div>{{ item.value }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

For the error, looks like you're cycling through the reference field, but you need to cycle through the values of a field inside the reference field. (I'm sure someone could explain this better, but entity holds the field values you want to loop)

Instead of:

```
{% for item in node.field_para %}
    {{ item.entity.field_cdsfasdf.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

try something more like:

```
{% for item in node.field_para.entity.field_cdsfasdf %}
    {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```